# MariaDB/MySQL Concat row values into dynamic columns

Tags: mariadb

I've searched the forum and can't find an example that matches what I'm trying to achieve so hopefully this is a new question.

I'm trying to concatenate all the values in a row and convert it to a column.  I want to create columns in the same fashion for all the rows in the table.  There will never be more than 3 or 4 rows.

For example purposes, assume a table called tbl1 with 3 fields as follows:

```
       f1  f2  f3
row 1  A   1   X
row 2  B   2   Y
row 3  C   3   Z
```

I want to take this data and create a query that will produce one row of data with these results:

```
c1         c2        c3
A, 1, X    B,2,Y     C,3,Z
```

Comment: How do we identify the row number ? Is there a primary key ?

Comment: Sorry, assume an auto increment primary key for each row but that value won't be used in the output.

Comment: can its value be assumed as 1,2,3 ?

Comment: Essentially, and to simplify the question, I'm trying to create a column for each row of data in the table consisting of the concatenated values from all the columns excluding the primary key.  The separator if irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, the primary can be 1, 2, 3 but I think where you're leading is the pk is always sequential.  That would usually be the case but if the user deletes a row at some point then it wouldn't.

Comment: one last question (hopefully): Are u using Mariadb version 10.3+ or MySQL 8+. Basically, does your version support window functions ? With window functions, we can solve the non-continuous PK problem.

Comment: You need `CONCAT` and pivoting.  See the tag I added.

Comment: MariaDB is running as an instance on Amazon RDS